# Projection of symmetric positive definite matrix onto an affine subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-optimization

Let $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $c > 0$ and

$$\mathcal{M} := \{X\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \mid b^{\top}Xb = c \}$$

Let $\mathcal{S}_n$ be the set of real $n \times n$ symmetric positive definite (SPD) matrices and $Q \in \mathcal{S}_n$. Let $\tilde{Q}$ be the projection of $Q$ onto $\mathcal{M}$. I want to know if $\tilde{Q}$ is still SPD.

I suspect it is not necessarily so, and in that case I would like to have an analytical expression for $\hat{Q}$, the projection of $Q$ onto $\mathcal{M} \cap \mathcal{S}_n$. Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, you're asking if $\tilde{Q} \subseteq Q$, correct?

Comment: What do you mean by $\tilde{Q} \subseteq Q$? I'm asking if $\tilde{Q} \in \mathcal{S}_n$.

Comment: Well, it's clearly not the case if $c<0$. But yes, sorry, I misread---$Q$ is a single matrix, not all of $\mathcal{S}_n$.

Answer (score 6):

Arin's answer is of course correct! Let's derive the formulate for the projection nevertheless. We will assume $b\neq 0$. The projection you're looking for is:
$$\hat{Q} = \mathop{\textrm{arg}\,\textrm{min}}_{X : b^T X b = c} \tfrac{1}{2} \|X-Q\|_F^2$$
The $\tfrac{1}{2}$ multiplier, and even the use of the *squared* norm, do not change the result but they do simplify the derivation. The Lagrangian is
$$L(X,\lambda) = \tfrac{1}{2} \langle X - Q, X - Q \rangle + \lambda ( c - b^TXb)$$
The optimality conditions are
$$X - Q - \lambda bb^T = 0, \quad b^TXb = c$$
Substituting for $X$ in the second equation gives
$$b^T(Q+\lambda bb^T)b = c \quad\Longrightarrow\quad \lambda = \frac{c - b^TQb}{(b^Tb)^2}$$
So we have
$$\tilde{Q} = Q + \frac{c-b^TQb}{(b^Tb)^2} bb^T$$
I'd say this makes intuitive sense: you add to $Q$ a multiple of $bb^T$ as needed to drive the quantity $b^T\tilde{Q}b$ to the correct value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For deriving $\hat{Q}$ I would need to solve a similar optimization problem, with the additional constraint that X is spd, but I would not know how to proceed since that is not a constraint that can be written as g(X) >= 0 (coordinate-wise) for some function g (or at least I don't know how to write it that way). Do you know how I could do that?

Comment: I see, so you want the projection on the set $\tilde{\mathcal{M}} = \left\{X\in\mathcal{S}_n\,:\,b^TXb=c\right\}$?

Comment: Yes, since $\tilde{Q}$ might not be in $\mathcal{S}_n$ I would like to project instead on $\tilde{\mathcal{M}} =\mathcal{M} \cap \mathcal{S}_n$.

Comment: Setting $X=B^TB$ we get the following problem : $\arg\,\min_{B \in \mathbb{R^{n\times n}}}\|B^TB - Q\|^2 + \lambda ( \|Bb\|^2 - c )$. I have no idea how tractable this is.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think the problem is indeed not tractable when using that substitution though, since one gets a cubic equation (in B) when applying the KKT conditions.

Comment: Yeah, that makes it non-convex. It's a straightforward semidefinite program, however, if you just add $X\succeq 0$ to the projection optimization problem. I don't know if it can be solved analytically, but I'd guess not.

Comment: Do you mean straightforward to solve analytically or to solve the optimization problem numerically?

Comment: I mean it probably _cannot_ be solved analytically. But it can be solved numerically as an SDP.

Comment: Oh, now I misread... I see, thanks!

Comment: Maybe try an alternating projection method (Dykstra, for example) to project on the affine and PSD set?

Comment: @whyyes that seems like a good option in this case. Projection onto the set of PSD matrices is quite simple if you're willing to do an eigenvalue decomposition---just zero out the negative eigenvalues.

Comment: By the way @MichaelGrant I'm trying to look at your solution to see if it's obvious why $\tilde Q$ is not in general PSD. Interestingly, if you do $b^T\tilde Q b$ (e.g. look at the component most in the direction of the negative term) then you get $b^T\tilde Q b >0$ whenever $c>0$. And, if $b$ is an eigenvector of $Q$, it also seems that $\tilde Q$ is PSD in general. Arin's is a very nice counterexample, but just out of curiousity, is there one in terms of $b$, $c$, and properties of $Q$ in general?

Comment: @whyyes Why is $b$ an eigenvector of $Q$? That's not an assumption. And the counterexample supplied by Arin is clear. I agree that if $b$ _happens_ to be an eigenvector, _and_ $c>0$, you're fine.

Comment: The span of the eigenvectors, I’m afraid, is not an interesting set of $Q$ is positive definite ;-)

Comment: (Sorry I deleted my comment, was going to expand on it) Yeah it's interesting that it is irrelevant since the full rank Q example has that counterexample! Anyway maybe I just have the wrong mental picture, but it seems like there might be some interesting geometry here!

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to show by a counterexample that $\tilde{Q}$ will not be SPD in general.

Let $Q = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & \sqrt{3} \\ \sqrt{3} & 2 \end{pmatrix}$, $b = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$, and $c=1.$ $\mathcal{M} = \{ X \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2} :x_{11} = 1\}.$  So $\tilde{Q} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \sqrt{3} \\ \sqrt{3} & 2\end{pmatrix}$ which is clearly not SPD as $\det \tilde{Q} < 0.$

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample!